How can I modify my formula to pull values based on up to four criteria instead of just one?
I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

I have the following formula in cell N2:
=let(Λ,transpose(bycol(B2:F,lambda(Σ,if(xmatch(O1,Σ),vstack(index(1:1,column(Σ)),join(", ",filter(A2:A,Σ=O1))))))),filter(Λ,index(Λ,,2)<>""))

This formula:

Searches the dataset B2:F for the value in O1.
Returns the corresponding results from B1:F1, removing blanks.
Checks the value in column L. If it is 0, nothing will display; if it is greater than 0, results will be displayed.
Display corresponding value matches found in column A2:A separated by commas if there is more than one

What I would like to do is expand this formula to account for up to four criteria (from cells O1 to R1) while still keeping the corresponding values from column A in the appropriate column. Additionally, if any cell in O1:R1 is blank, it should be disregarded as criteria.
Here is an example of expected results:

Link to sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tprQIYEMgLRuyCMCQ0cDO_JDzWKdW-eTyXH76HJTeic

Would you be open to trying using Google Apps Script for this?

Unfortunately no, Google Apps Script will not work.

“Unfortunately no, Google Apps Script will not work.”  I can’t see any reason why an apps script would not work in this scenario. Perhaps you have a particular reason for saying “will not work”.  Would you please elaborate.

The sheet is needed to be fully functional immediately after being copied. My understanding is that Google Apps Script requires initial setup to work after being copied.

“The sheet is needed to be fully functional immediately after being copied”. Ok. That’s something that ought to be mentioned in the body of the question. (The copying bit, I mean).

@Tedinoz and falcon4ch If you use custom functions, copying would work flawlessly.

If you use custom functions, copying would work flawlessly Quite right; thank you @TheMaster Purely as a matter of interest, do you think a custom function "might/could" be an option here?

@Tedinoz Yes, but if it can be done with inbuilt formula, it does have several advantages: no network delay and offline access.

Try the following in N2 instead of your original formula:
=arrayformula(let(
flatTbl,query(to_text(split(tocol(B1:F1&"|"&A2:A14&"|"&B2:F14),"|",,1)),"where Col2 is not null and Col3 is not null",0),
uniquePerCol,tocol(map(O1:R1,lambda(x,ifna(unique(filter(choosecols(flatTbl,1),choosecols(flatTbl,3)=x))))),1),
shared,unique(filter(uniquePerCol,countif(uniquePerCol,uniquePerCol)=counta(O1:R1))),
sortShared,sort(shared,match(shared,B1:F1,0),1),
lookups,makearray(counta(sortShared),columns(O1:R1),lambda(r,c,textjoin(", ",1,ifna(query(flatTbl,"select Col2 where Col1='"&chooserows(sortShared,r)&"' and Col3='"&choosecols(O1:R1,c)&"'",0))))),
{sortShared,lookups}))

I'm not going to try to explain this!

One minor thing - I noticed that if "Bird" meets the criteria specified it is always in the list first. Would it be possible to adjust so that B1:F1 are in order? Otherwise this is great, thank you!

I've tweaked the formula so that results are returned in B1:F1 order as requested (there was an unnecessary SORT within the 'shared' expression)

The formula now puts "Rabbit" and "Bird" at the top (see screenshot below). Apologies if I wasn't clear - I'd like the order to go in B1, C1, D1, E1, F1. https://i.imgur.com/QMSyi9g.png

Ah OK, now I think I've understood - I've updated the formula again.

Modularize your existing formula as a  LAMBDA and call that function by iterating O1:R1 BYCOL:
=LET(
 yourFormula, LAMBDA(o,ifna(transpose(bycol(B2:F,lambda(Σ,if(xmatch(o,Σ),vstack(join(", ",filter(A2:A,Σ=o))))))))),
 HSTACK(TRANSPOSE(B1:F1),BYCOL(O1:R1,yourFormula))
)


I like it; so much shorter and more simple. But it returns values for "Bird", "Snake" and "Rabbit" where they do not have values in each of the "query" fields.

@Tedinoz Yeah, I did work on an update to filter it out after this, but didn't update it here, as OP didn't respond and the bounty was already given.  Maybe I'll update it now...(Edit: Nvm, I deleted it... too much work to get it from version history..)
